# Use different delete behavior in admin-django and models.CASCADE

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models, one referencing the other with a ForeignKey. Something like this:

```py
class Data(models.Model):
   [some fields]

class Backup(models.Model):
   data_source = models.ForeignKey(Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   storage_destination = models.ForeginKey(S3Bucket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The behavior I want is that After the deletion of a "Data" instance, Its backups get deleted from the S3 bucket (I can handle this by invoking a Temporal workflow like DeleteFromS3Workflow, no Django hack is needed), and after the completion of DeleteFromS3Workflow, the "Backup" model gets deleted from the database. Beyond this, I want to be able to delete a "Backup" object from Django admin without invoking the Temporal workflow and directly deleting the object from the database (the thing uncustomized delete() method of the model does).
Overwriting the delete() method on the "Backup" model doesn't satisfy this as long as it deletes the model before the completion of workflow and this behavior is mutual in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own custom `on_delete` function that replicates the `CASCADE` function but adds your S3 deletion. This way you can preserve the default `delete()` function of your model so that it works as normal in the Django admin.

```py
data_source = models.ForeignKey(Data, on_delete=CASCADE_S3_WORKFLOW)
```

If you look at the Django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ab1955a05e369337c3eaad1a2d34de346932179d/django/db/models/deletion.py#L22) you can see what `CASCADE` does: